# Absolute entropy of a compound at a given temperature is S0→T=∫Cp(T)Tdt + ΔH(trans)/T(trans).Is there an assumption of constant pressure here?

Tags: thermodynamics

Change in entropy of system is given by dQrev/T, Qrev=nCpdT for ideal gas only at constant pressure,so when we find absolute entropy of a gas by integrating nCpdT from 0K, is constnat pressure maintained? It doesn't seem practical that a solid at 0K and when you take it to a gas, that gas and that solid have the same pressure which is needed to apply the mentioned formula.

Comment: Yes, it's possible for p to be constant. You can change T to go from condensed to gas phase.

Comment: Note also your equations contain errors. Should be $dq_{rev}=nC_p dT$, for instance.